# Spark union fails with nested JSON dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, union, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two JSON files:

```
{
    "name" : "Agent1",
    "age" : "32",
    "details" : [{
            "d1" : 1,
            "d2" : 2
        }
    ]
}

{
    "name" : "Agent2",
    "age" : "42",
    "details" : []
}
```

I read them with spark:

```
val jsonDf1 = spark.read.json(pathToJson1)
val jsonDf2 = spark.read.json(pathToJson2)
```

two dataframes are created with the following schemas:

```
root
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- d1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

root
|-- age: string (nullable = true)
|-- details: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

When I try to perform a union with these two dataframes I get this error:

```
jsonDf1.union(jsonDf2)


org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'Union;;
'Union
:- LogicalRDD [age#0, details#1, name#2]
+- LogicalRDD [age#7, details#8, name#9]
```

How can I resolve this? I will get empty arrays sometimes in the JSON files the spark job will load, but it will still have to unify them, which shouldn't be a problem since the schema of the Json files is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

polomarcus's answer led me to this solution: 
I couldn't read all the files at once because I got a list of files as input, and spark didn't have an API that receives a list of paths, but apparently with Scala it's possible to do this:

```
val files = List("path1", "path2", "path3")
val dataframe = spark.read.json(files: _*)
```

This way I got one dataframe containing all three files.

Answer (score 5):

If you try to union the 2 dataframes you will get this :

`error:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. ArrayType(StringType,true) <> ArrayType(StructType(StructField(d1,StringType,true), StructField(d2,StringType,true)),true) at the second column of the second table`

### Json files arrive at the same time

To solve this problem, if you can read the JSON at the same time, I would suggest :

`val jsonDf1 = spark.read.json("json1.json", "json2.json")`

This will give this schema:

```
jsonDf1.printSchema
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- d1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

The data output

```
jsonDf1.show(10,truncate = false)
+---+-------+------+
|age|details|name  |
+---+-------+------+
|32 |[[1,2]]|Agent1|
|42 |null   |Agent2|
+---+-------+------+
```

### Json files arrive at different times

If your json arrive at different times, as a default solution, I would recommend to read a template JSON object with a full array, that will make your dataframe with a possible empty array valid for any union. Then, you will remove with a filter this fake JSON before outputting the result:

```
val df = spark.read.json("jsonWithMaybeAnEmptyArray.json", 
"TemplateFakeJsonWithAFullArray.json")

df.filter($"name" !== "FakeAgent").show(1)
```

**Please note** : A Jira card has been opened to improve capability to merge SQL data types: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19536 and this kind of operation should be possible in the next Spark version.

Comment: Thank you, this does solve this issue, the problem is that i'm getting multiple json files (which are then converted to ORC), so I can't use this solution. the read function can't receive a list of file path, or one concatenated string of paths. So I have to perform a union between DF and then i face the same issue again :\

Comment: Even if you use wildcards in your path like this : `spark.read.json("JsonPathWithWildcards*.json").show(10, truncate = false)`  ?